# Is there a way to simulate multiple locations over time like 'City Run' on a device?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently in the iOS simulator you can simulate a City Run which changes your location over time.
You can also simulate your location on an iOS device but only individual coordinates. Is it possible to simulate something like a City Run but on a device?

Comment: seen this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html ?

Comment: Like I said I'm aware of being able to set individual coordinates, I'm after a way to automate the location coordinates changing over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using a GPX file(http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GPX).  Similar as to how you would simulate location found https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/articles/simulating_locations.html you can upload a GPX file that hold information including multiple GPS points.

Another option depending on what you are trying to do is use a subclass of a CLLocationManager to read data from a file. There is an example of this here (https://github.com/Raizlabs/RZLocationSimulationManager/tree/develop) unfortunately there isn't any sample code with it, but you should be able to get an idea of how it is done from the code.

Comment: That's probably going to be the best there is, thanks for linking to that repo Alex!